# Wamp server aestan tray menu internal error

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, wamp, wampserver

I installed wamp server 32bit my computer have windows 8.1 64bit I installed all Microsoft c++ versions but wamp server not get green I tried install Apache service but aestan menu show this message to me:

> could not execute menu item internal error eaccessviolation violation d'acces a' l'adresse 0046B932 dans le module 'wampmanager.exe' . lecture de 'l adresse 0000000B

What do I do now?

Comment: Did you install WAMPServer from an Admin account?

Comment: Did you install ALL the MSVC Runtimes for the 32bit environment as well as the 64bit environment?

Comment: Run this little tool [from the WAMPServer backup repo called "Checks VC++ packages installed"](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en)

Comment: I installed all msvc runtimes setups

Comment: Riggsfolly it's not worked for me